# How to exclude test classes from PIT mutation test with maven command line arguments?

Tags: java, maven, pitest

I'm trying to run the mutation tests for all the unit tests, so I need to exclude the integration tests from the run.

I've tried these commands without success:

```
mvn pitest:mutationCoverage -DExcludedClasses='**IntegrationTest'
```

```
mvn pitest:mutationCoverage -DExcludedTests='path.to.integrationtest.package.**'
```

[This page](https://pitest.org/quickstart/commandline/) states that there is a way to exclude with the `--ExcludedClasses='**'` parameter, but I guess that this one is meant for lauching it with `java` command intead of maven.

So my question is: Is there a parameter that I can use to exclude tests when running with `mvn pitest:mutationCoverage` command on commandLine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to exclude test classes is `excludedTestClasses`. This is case sensitive (standard maven behaviour), you seem to be capitalising the first letter which means it will not be recognised.

```
mvn pitest:mutationCoverage -DexcludedTestClasses='com.example.integrationtests.*'
```

Will work.

Remember that the glob is matched again pacakge names, not file paths, and as you are invoking the goal directly you will need to have run `mvn test` or `mvn test-compile` first to ensure all required bytecode is present.

The following link, which covers the running pitest on a project for the first time, might be useful.

https://docs.arcmutate.com/docs/basic-maven-setup

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Maven plugin quickstart documentation for Pitest](https://pitest.org/quickstart/maven/) there's a `excludedTestClasses` configuration parameter where you can specify which tests should be excluded. So assuming all your integration tests are in the same package you should be able to do something like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludedTestClasses>
            <param>path.to.integrationtest.package*</param>
        </excludedTestClasses>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

EDIT:

In order to have it accessible on the command line you could [create a profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) activated by a property, and use that property to set the plugin configuration. Maven merges the configuration by default, giving you the result you want.

Something like this (untested):

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>excludedTestPackage</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
        <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludedTestClasses>
            <param>${excludedTestPackage}</param>
          </excludedTestClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

And to activate it when invoking Maven:

`mvn pitest:mutationCoverage -DexcludedTestPackage=path.to.integrationtest.package*`

Comment: Yes, I've found this documentation, but I need both configurations (Ideally without changing the `pom.xml`). When the mutation tests run on CI/CD server, it'll run the default pitest mutation command (and I can't change that, unfortunately). But I also wan't to run the tests quickly on my local environment to check if the changes I introduced kill all the mutations. I need a way to set this configuration as a command line parameter of maven.

Comment: TL;DR 
I need something like this  `mvn pitest:mutationCoverage --exclude='this.package.**'`

Comment: It should be possible to do with a Maven profile, see my updated answer.